# AWS Sns publish silently dies when device is disabled?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, notifications, publish, amazon-sns

I am hitting a strange error when I attempt to call $sns->publish (PHP) - it never returns, I am not sure if it dies silently, but I could not catch an exception or get a return code. 
I was able to track this down to happen when device for the token (endpoint) appears to be already disabled in the SNS console. It gets disabled on the initial call, I would assume due to the error returned by GCM that token is invalid.
What am I doing wrong and how can I prevent the problem? I do not want to check every endpoint for being enabled since I may be pushing to 10 out of 1000. However I definitely want to continue executing my push loop.
Any thoughts? AWS team forum seems useless, it has been weeks since original reply by AWS team member asking for code with not response since that time.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the endpoint is disabled before sending push notification as -

```
$arn_code = ARN_CODE_HERE;
$arn_arr = array("EndpointArn"=>$arn_code);
$endpointAtt = $sns->getEndpointAttributes($arn_arr);
//print_r($endpointAtt);
if($endpointAtt != 'failed' && $endpointAtt['Attributes']['Enabled'] != 'false')
{
     ....PUBLISH CODE HERE....
}
```

It will not stop the execution.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: as I said: "I do not want to check every endpoint for being enabled since I may be pushing to 10 out of 1000."

Comment: Then its not possible. What i'm doing for this is every time i'm taking a Device Token from User and registering / creating endPoint for that on AWS. Doesn't mater its already register there or not and sending the parameter always as Enabled => true. So if that endpoint was disable before will get enabled again. So i never get a condition where endpoint is made disabled while sending SNS.

Comment: it should not just die :-) it should return with failure of some sort not die

Comment: I know, i was facing the same issue. But now found another solution as to add 'try catch' code for every $sns request and response. So it will not die the execution. And you will get the exact issue in exception message.

Comment: Tried that as well. The code just dies not even an exception :-)